# How can I share my internet connection using a router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, connection-sharing, subnet

How can I share my internet connection using a router?

I get 192.168.1.150 from my provider and 192.168.1.1 as a DNS server, mask is 255.255.255.0

I suppose 150 is my gateway now.

What IP should have the router set? What addresses, masks and other settings should the PCs in my LAN have?

EDIT:

192.168.1.150 is the address of the access point. I connect another access point with router to the other one and want to have another subnet. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify, please? Who is "your provider"? If your computer's address is `192.168.1.150` you are already using a router, which has the address `192.168.1.1`. Are you connecting your computer wirelessly? If so, you can probably just attach another computer, and it will get its IP address automatically from this router. If not, you should really explain more about your situation.

Comment: Please tell us how your PC is connected to the router, and [edit] and post a copy of `ipconfig /all`

Comment: Your ISP is not assigning you 192.168.1.150  as an ip address.  That is a local network ip address, its an invalid public ip address, and does not exist outside of your local network.

Comment: @Ramhound In some cases, ISP may in fact provide such an address and ISP's "LAN" may be connected to the Internet.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router is the device that connects two different networks together. So you must theoretically have two different networks on both sides of your router.

From what you have written in your question I suggest that that is not your provider, but rather your router that assigns you the IPs you provided: `192.168.*.*` is common for local network topologies, not for WAN addresses. The only strange things here seems to be your DNS, that is usually not the same server as your GateWay.

On the other side you might also be in the situation common in many dormitories where your "provider" is your landlord or home management office and you get the IPs from the local network assigned to your personally. Since you mention using the router this seems to be the address assigned to your router, not to your private PC. In this case you can just connect as many clients to your router as you want, both using cable or wirelessly and they all will use the shared line for Internet connection.

You don't have to configure your clients beforehand, rather you better activate the DHCP service on your router so that the latter will automatically distribute the available IP address pool to your clients and manage those (having certain expriration time etc.).